# iOS simulator always saves images on desktop

Tags: ios, xcode-simulator

When pressed Command-S, the iOS simulator always saves screenshots on Desktop. How can I tell it to save it somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit to add Automator steps]

You can't change the location, but I often use a little script like this to keep things tidy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

destination=~/screenshots

while [ true ]; do
    if [ -n "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo ~/Desktop/Simulator\ Screen\ Shot*.png)" ]; then
        mv -v ~/Desktop/Simulator\ Screen\ Shot*.png "$destination";
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Since you're using the iOS simulator you probably know how to create this as an executable script already, so I'll avoid giving those instructions.

If not, I might use Automator.

- Create folder screenshots in your home directory
- Start Automator and create a new Document of type Application
- Find the Run Shell Script action and drag it from the actions on the left to the workspace on the right
- Paste the shell script without the first line with #! stuff
- Save it and run it from applications
- You should see the screen shot files be moved.
- Here's a visual. http://www.screencast.com/t/KEbAFifHCTcc

Comment: Thank you! Actually I stick to xcode and spend as little time as possible with the Terminal app. Basically save as .command and run, right?

Comment: Cool, since that is the case, I might use Automator.
- Create folder screenshots in your home directory
- Start Automator and create a new Document of type Application
- Find the Run Shell Script action and drag it from the actions on the left to the workspace on the right
- Paste the shell script without the first line with #! stuff
- Save it and run it from applications
- You should see the screen shot files be moved.
- Here's a visual. http://www.screencast.com/t/KEbAFifHCTcc

Comment: If you choose Folder Action when making the Automator document, you can attach this to the Desktop folder, and macOS will run the script in the background automatically. Remove the `while`, `sleep`, and `done` lines from the script - the system will take care of that

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the location where Simulator.app saves screenshots.